# Android - How to set gravity of tabWidget?

Tags: android, gravity, tabwidget, fragment-tab-host

I have created a FragmentTabHost and it works correctly, but I want to set gravity of tabs to right. I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setLayoutParams(params);
```

My XML layout file is as follow:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >    
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please change into this code.

```
<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

There is no need of programmatically code.